# Amazon SES advantage of SMTP over plain SES

Tags: smtp, throttling, amazon-ses

Does anyone know if there is any advantage of using Amazon SES SMTP option vs. plain SES?

We are running over our limits and I'd like to use a third-party package that includes throttling, but they only support it for plain SES.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, limits will grow if you sent many mails via SES, And what limit you reached? Mail per seconds? Daily limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a performance advantage, but if you design your email sender to use the SMTP interface you can easily switch to another sending service by changing destination server/port if SES doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is no longer relevant, but I appreciate you taking the time to answer me.